# Python проверка существования файла по расширению

Tags: python, файлы

Я просто голову сломал, что не так?

Если файл существует все ок. Если его нет мне надо проделать следующую часть кода, но ничего не происходит! Print не выводит.

Я перепробовал разные способы, этот мне показался самый простой.

Так же в папке присутствуют и другие файлы с другими расширениями.

```
for file in os.listdir('C:\pdd'):
    if file.endswith(".004"):
        if not file:
            print('Пусто')
        else:
            print(os.path.join(file))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для поиска файлов по расширению можно использовать [wildcard](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)

#### Через glob:

```
from glob import glob

for file in glob(r'C:\Program Files\**\*.jpg', recursive=True):
    print('[glob]', file)
```

#### Через pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

for file in Path(r'C:\Program Files').rglob('*.jpg'):
    print('[pathlib]', file)
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас и так уже идет проверка на существование `if file.endswith(".004"):`
Поэтому `if not file` не выполнится
вынесите эту проверку на уровень с `if file.endswith(".FDB")`

```
import os
for file in os.listdir('D:\\'):
    if file.endswith(".FDB"):
        print(os.path.join(file))
        
    else:
        print('Пусто')
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, немного непонятно, зачем нужна вторая проверка. Может быть, чтобы читать файл? Но это делается немного по-другому.

```
for file in os.listdir('api'):
    if file.endswith(".004"):
        if not file:
            print('Пусто')
        else:
            print(os.path.join(file))
    else:
        print(f'Файл {file} не заканчивается на это')
```